# Использование goto в обработке исключений

Tags: исключения, try-catch, goto

Как можно иначе обрабатывать ввод с клавиатуры переменных, без использования goto? целью является наличие обработки при повторных попытках ввода

```
Input:
        try
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите тип ввода массива 1-ручной 2-автоматический");
        MassiveInpiut(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        //Использование goto?
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Число B");

            IndexEqual(Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
            goto Input;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Выберите тип ввода массива 1-ручной 2-автоматический");
                MassiveInpiut(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
                Console.WriteLine("Введите Число B");
                IndexEqual(Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine()));
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Проверка корректности будет выполняться каждый раз при таком подходе. Если данные, введенные пользователем, не валидны, ему снова предлагается ввести данные, и снова будет проверяться их валидность. Блок try срабатывает каждый раз.

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь срабатывает так как нужно. Если я правильно понял то break выполняет выход из цикла запросов ввода если не было допущено ошибок?

Comment: Именно так. В примере ниже просто получался бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Так: ?

```
while(true) {
    try
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Выберите тип ввода массива 1-ручной 2-автоматический");
    MassiveInpiut(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    Console.WriteLine("Введите Число B");

        IndexEqual(Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
        continue;

    }
break;
}
```

Comment: В данном случае код исполняется повторно даже при отсутствии ошибок ввода. У меня после успешного ввода должен выводится результат работы функции, а так он просто заново запускает ввод

Comment: Возможно я неправильно поставил цель. Для прояснения : без goto я могу просто продублировать код из try в catch для повторного запроса ввода от пользователя но тогда этот повторный ввод будет без обработки. И вот я сомневаюсь что будет правильно написать ещё одну вложенную обработку, ведь мне важно наличие проверки даже если пользователь неправильно хоть 100 раз ввёл данные. Додумался только до goto с возвращением к началу блока try